# Change priority of mdns4 hostname resolution

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, host-name-resolution, mdns

We are using a Raspberry Pi which has a Lidar connected to the ethernet port. The problem is that the mdns4_minimal resolves $(hosname).local into two IPs. One IP is obtained from the ethernet port (from Lidar) and another from WiFi. This results in a problem with ROS that some nodes get the Lidar's IP address instead of WiFi's IP address which results in nodes not being able to correctly communicate with each other.

I think that the solution could be to change the priority of hostname resolution to prioritize WiFi connection, but I didn't find any instructions on the internet of how to do that.

Or is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can specify the name resolution priority (or rather, *order*) in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

For example, on a Raspbian 11 (bullseye) Pi, the relevant section of the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

For example, if you put `dns` before mdns4_minimal, the hostname resolution will favour dns over mdns:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

See [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) here and an excellent post detailing resolve order [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1417190/why-do-i-need-to-change-the-order-of-hosts-in-nsswitch-conf).

Upon reading your comments, I understand you would like to keep the mDNS resolving in place, but dictate which *interfaces* are involved in that process.

You can instruct the Avahi daemon (responsible for mDNS) to ignore an interface by adding said interface to the `deny-interfaces` list in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`. From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/avahi-daemon.conf.5.html):

```
deny-interfaces= Set a comma separated list of network interfaces that should be ignored by avahi-daemon. Other not specified interfaces will be used, unless allow-interfaces= is  set.
       This option takes precedence over allow-interfaces=.
```

Afterwards, restart the daemon with `systemctl restart avahi-daemon`.

Comment: But if I correctly understand the nsswitch.conf, "dns" resolves through an online dns. I want to resolve with a local dns service (mdns). I want the IP to be resolved to the local IP of the device, not to lookup for $(hosname).local on a online dns, because that hostname can't be resolved with an online dns.

Comment: OK, I now get what you mean. The `files` option is always prioritized, that means the entries in the `/etc/hosts` file. Does your usecase allow for adding static entries in that file?

Comment: No, our robots are meant to be used with a DHCP router, it would be a hassle to assign a static IP to each robot.

Comment: And is it feasible to block (iptables, nftables etc) outgoing multicast DNS traffic over the ethernet (Lidar) interface?

Comment: I think that would be feasible, because we are connecting to the Lidar through the IP address anyway. But how to do that?

Comment: I'm editing my post - I've got another idea.

Comment: This works great, thanks. But if I understand correctly it will now be a bit more difficult to debug through the ethernet port when connected to the router with UTP cable, right? I won't be able to ssh to the robot with $(hostname).local? Because that's the other use of the ethernet port